# How do I make this document print out in a two sided manner, at least have two pages within one page?

Tags: formatting

Below is what I have tried but it does not work, I am not sure how to do this at all:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.1in,paperheight=89mm,paperwidth=141mm,twosided{geometry}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
% \newgeometry{twosided} % I also try it here and it does not work.

Scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar 
neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl 
tincidunt eget nullam non nisi est sit amet facilisis magna etiam tempor orci 
eu lobortis elementum nibh tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa enim nec 
dui nunc mattis enim ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut diam 
quam nulla porttitor massa id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit cursus 
risus at ultrices mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget 
gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur 
ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel risus 
commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat est velit 
egestas dui id ornare arcu odio ut sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet nisl 
suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor elit sed 
vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc 
pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero nunc consequat 
interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus 
luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero 
justo laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit amet justo donec enim diam 
vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam.


\newpage


Scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar 
neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl 
tincidunt eget nullam non nisi est sit amet facilisis magna etiam tempor orci 
eu lobortis elementum nibh tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa enim nec 
dui nunc mattis enim ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut diam 
quam nulla porttitor massa id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit cursus 
risus at ultrices mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget 
gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur 
ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel risus 
commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat est velit 
egestas dui id ornare arcu odio ut sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet nisl 
suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor elit sed 
vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc 
pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero nunc consequat 
interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus 
luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero 
justo laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit amet justo donec enim diam 
vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam.


\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you add a picture illustrating what your desired end result is? It's unclear to me what you mean by "having two pages on one page" and how that relates to the `twoside` option.

Comment: I am not sure 100% if it relates either, but basically each section is `paperheight=89mm and paperwidth=141mm` ideally I want the totality of the document to be this in height and width but across this times two, imagine printing it and it prints on both back and front, because at the moment it will print out on two pages rather than one. Here is an example picture of what double sided printing looks like: https://www.bestqualityprinter.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/duplex.jpg

Comment: The `twoside` option changes the margins of the type area so that when they are for example bound in a book, the type area has different spacing to the binding (the inner side) than to the outer side (the link you posted in your answer explains just this concept). How you in fact print on both sides of the paper is not controlled by your file, but by the printer (or the printer driver), or the software you print from.

Comment: Makes sense, post as an answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `twoside` option provides a two- (or *double*) sided layout, in which the margins of the type area are set in such a way that they would work in a doublepage, such as in a book.

So for example the following code using `twoside`

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=89mm,paperwidth=141mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\blindtext[4]

\end{document}
```

produces this layout, where the binding margins (towards the 'inner part' of the doublepage) are smaller than the ones to the fore edge (towards the 'outer' part of the doublepage):

[image: doublepage]

Defining a fixed margin (such as `margin=0.1in`) overrides `twoside` and makes it obsolete. (If you want to define your own margins in a doublepage layout you have to do it via the `geometry` options `inner` and `outer`.) Since you want `margin=0.1in`, you don't need to use `twoside`.

How both sides of the paper can be printed is a different issue. This is not controlled by the file being printed, but by the printer (or the printer driver) itself, and varies depending on the printer or software used to hand the printer the instructions... (Or maybe just print half of your document and put the paper back in the printer upside-down, then print the second half.)

Answer (score 0):

I worked out that by following this tutorial I can just do:

```
\documentclass[twoside,10pt]{article}
```

[Overleaf two sided docs overview](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Single_sided_and_double_sided_documents)

Comment: Since you use `margin=0.1in` in the question, the twoside option will have no effect, because it expects that you define the margins in terms of `inner=` and `outer=`. I'm not sure this answers the question you posted.

Comment: How would I rectify this with desired margins in tact?

Comment: `twoside` has nothing to do with printing on both sides of a paper. Printing on both sides of a paper is controlled by your printer/printer driver. (See my second comment under the question.)